# Carousel item invoking another intent (not the followup actions_intent_option)

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I need some help here. I have a google assistant food recipes bot with the following intents:

```
[GET_RECIPES_BY_NAME]
[GET_RECIPES_BY_CAROUSEL]
-----[GET_OPTION]
```

So, when the user says "I want a chocolate cake", the dialogflow invokes the [GET_RECIPES_BY_NAME].

When user says "See menu", the bot shows the carousel. But, when the user taps the item, the dialogflow is invoking the [GET_RECIPES_BY_NAME] too, not the [GET_OPTION].

It is using/returning the title instead of the option/key.
[GET_OPTION] intent was set as followup with the context and event actions_intent_OPTION.

The flow is a little bit more complex, but I revised it to make it more comprehensible. All the intents handles are in the fulfillment.

I tried many solutions: [GET_OPTION] as followup, as in the first level, deleting and recreating all the contexts in fulfillment....and so on, and nothing.

An important detail: recipes that don't not have the training in [GET_RECIPES_BY_NAME] call correctly in the [GET_OPTION].

My question is this: If I set any followup intent and set it with the event actions_intent_OPTION, shouldn't this always be invoked when I tap the carousel item?

Comment: On the surface, this should work as you expect. Can you update your question with details so we can see exactly what is going on and try to duplicate? (Screen shots of the Intents in question and the exact output that is generating the carousel might help a lot.)